# Is it possible to make a typedef only visible to child classes?

Tags: c++, templates

Given:

```
template <...>
class InheritedByManyClasses
{
public:
    typedef InheritedByManyClasses<...> ParentClass;
};
```

If I make a child of that which is *also* a parent of more classes, is there any way to chain this idea together?

```
template<...>
class ChildInheritedByMany : InheritedByManyClasses<...>
{
public:
    typedef ... ParentClass;  // oops!  now this class can't benefit from parent typedef
};
```

Is there some way I can make a `typedef` in the child that's only visible to *its* children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't.  All members are always visible to the current class.  However, there's a simple workaround:

```
template<typename T>
struct base_typedef_shim : T
{
     typedef T ParentClass;

     // the usual C++11 perfect constructor forwarding stuffs
};

template <...>
class InheritedByManyClasses
{
};

template<...>
class ChildInheritedByMany : public base_typedef_shim<InheritedByManyClasses<...>>
{
};

template<...>
class GrandChild : public base_typedef_shim<ChildInheritedByMany<...>>
{
};
```

Comment: I learned something from every answer, but this one comes closest to answering what I was *trying* to ask.

Answer (score 5):

```
using
```

---

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  protected:
    using V = std::vector<T>;   
};

template<typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
  protected:
    typename A<T>::V i;
  public:
    using A<T>::V;  // If you want to make it public now

};

int main() { 
    // A<int>::V i;  // Not visible
    B<int>::V i;  // visible
}
```

Comment: +1 from me. I actually got told off by my boss for using `using` in production code.

Answer (score 2):

Make it `protected` and put `typedef` in children sequentially:

```
struct A
{
};

struct B : public A
{
protected:
    typedef A Parent;
};

struct C : public B
{
protected:
    typedef B Parent;
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP means. If I understand correctly, they want to have a name to refer to the base class `B` in a derived class `D` *and* at the same time have the *same* name to be used in class `E` that derives from `D` to refer to `D`. I may be misunderstanding though

Comment: @AndyProwl: Updated. Is it possible to have automated _typedef_ for children classes? I think he should define _typedefs_ manually in all of children.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did actually misunderstand what the OP wants. I think @BenVoigt's answer clarifies it

Comment: @Andy: No, I think you understood fine.  I looked at your comment before writing my answer, and decided that was most likely the correct interpretation of the original request... so I made `ParentType` refer to `InheritedByMany` from within `Child` and the same (unqualified) name refer to `Child` from within `GrandChild`.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `typedef` into the child class instead:

```
template<...>
class ChildInheritedByMany : InheritedByManyClasses<...>
{
public:
    typedef InheritedByManyClasses<...> ParentClass;
};
```

Also, depending on your use case, `std::is_base_of` might come in handy.